# Python: how to make if else for loops faster, when first value differs from any other?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, loops, numpy

I am dealing with a function that looks like this:

```
def A(x):
   A=range(n)
   A[0]=(bx[0] if condition1 else cx[0])
   for i in range(1,n):
            A[i]=((dx[i] if condition2 else ex[i])

   return  map(lambda x: x+3, A)
```

where A is a list and b,c,d,e are operations that take x as variable.
Basically, I need to make an if statement for the first value in the A-list, and a different if statement for any other value apart from the first one. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

thank you

Comment: With [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) it's possible to optimise loops. Can you be more specific about b,c,d,e operations?

Comment: b,c,d,e are functions like: min(x*6/3600, 100-x/0,5), or (x*6, x-3), etc....I didn't want to over complicate the question, but they are not complex functions

Comment: @Luca91, why returning `map` instead of `list` ?

Comment: no particular reason, I was trying different things to end up with a list.

Comment: Is it intentional that your list elements are generators?

Comment: I need to call the same function multiple times and within other loops and constraints, therefore I defined A(x) as a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
def A(x):
   A = np.arange(n)
   A[0] = (bx[0] if condition1 else cx[0])
   A[1:] = np.where(condition2, dx[1:], ex[1:])

   return A + 3
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of code restructuring - at least 2 optimizations can be applied in that context:

- prevent double `range()` call
- prevent redundant looping caused by `map` call (just to add `3` to each item)

Optimized version:

```
def func(x):
   res = [((bx[0] if condition1 else cx[0]) if i == 0 
          else (dx[i] if condition2 else ex[i])) + 3 
          for i in range(0, n)]

   return res
```

Comment: You may want to start with `res = [...]` instead of appending a single value to an empty list. But at least you now have working code :-)

Comment: Also, a list comprehension would perform better than repeated appends.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I know it goes faster, just went for readability. Ok, let's do it